# IOGear GBU521 Bluetooth adapter on Debian

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez

I've been trying to install a GBU521 Bluetooth adapter on Debian. I've been following several guides, one for Raspbian (http://www.ioncannon.net/linux/1570/bluetooth-4-0-le-on-raspberry-pi-with-bluez-5-x/), and one for Linux Mint (https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/14340) (which should work on Debian), but still get the error "No adapters found" with Blueman and it doesn't show up on `hciconfig`.

So how do I get the IOGear GBU521 Bluetooth adapter working on Debian? If you need any more information, just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by compiling a new kernel with the option `CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB=y`.